# Uploading files in chunks with blueimp in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blueimp

I try to put the plugin blueimp to my Asp.Net MVC application. 
My upload target is about 1GB. 
How to handle chunk file upload fle in server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean FileUpload jquery module from blueimp. This is how I handle it in my project. I upload large images that don't go over 30MB. So this example is merely about the code, not the fact that you need to handle 1GB files.

This is part of the javascript code. There's nothing special. I just follow the FileUpload documentation and example. I just send couple more properties (inlcuding AntiforgeryToken) - that are not required for the correct behavior.

```
$("#file-upload").fileupload({
    url: 'upload-file',
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    maxChunkSize: 5000000,
    progressInterval: 1000,
    bitrateInterval: 1000
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    fileData = data; // save data to be able to submit them later

    if (window.File && window.Blob) {
        // update form data
        data.formData = {
            uploadFolder: '/upload-folder/some-guid',
            __RequestVerificationToken: $("#upload-form").find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
        };
    } else {
        // chunk upload not supported
    }
});

$("#file-submit").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fileData.submit();
});
```

On the server side I have a model class:

```
public class UploadViewRequest
{
    public Guid UploadFolder { get; set; }
    public bool IsChunk { get; set; }
    public int ChunkNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirst { get; set; }
    public bool IsLast { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase OriginalFile { get; set; }
    public bool JsonAccepted { get; set; }
}
```

And I wrote a custom model binder for this class, so that I can see if it's whole file or just a chunk and if yes, that what part of the file I'm going to process:

```
public class UploadViewRequestBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        UploadViewRequest model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as UploadViewRequest;

        string rangeHeader = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Content-Range"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rangeHeader))
            model.IsChunk = false;
        else
        {
            model.IsChunk = true;

            Match match = Regex.Match(rangeHeader, "^bytes ([\\d]+)-([\\d]+)\\/([\\d]+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            int bytesFrom = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            int bytesTo = int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value);
            int bytesFull = int.Parse(match.Groups[3].Value);

            if (bytesTo == bytesFull)
                model.IsLast = true;
            else
                model.IsLast = false;

            if (bytesFrom == 0)
            {
                model.ChunkNumber = 1;
                model.IsFirst = true;
            }
            else
            {
                int bytesSize = bytesTo - bytesFrom + 1;
                model.ChunkNumber = (bytesFrom / bytesSize) + 1;
                model.IsFirst = false;
            }
        }

        if (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null && controllerContext.HttpContext.Request["HTTP_ACCEPT"].Contains("application/json"))
            model.JsonAccepted = true;
        else
            model.JsonAccepted = false;

        return model;
    }
}
```

and this is the controller action method:

```
public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewRequest request)
{
    var path = ''; // create path
    FileStatus status = null;

    try
    {
        if (request.IsChunk)
        {
            if (request.IsFirst )
            {
                // do some stuff that has to be done before the file starts uploading
            }

            var inputStream = request.OriginalFile.InputStream;

            using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024];

                var l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                while (l > 0)
                {
                    fs.Write(buffer, 0, l);
                    l = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
                }

                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
            }

            status = new FileStatus(new FileInfo(path));

            if (request.IsLast) 
            {
                // do some stuff that has to be done after the file is uploaded
            }
        }
        else
        {
            file.SaveAs(path);
            status = new FileStatus(new FileInfo(path));
        } 
    } catch {
        status = new FileStatus 
        {
            error = "Something went wrong"
        };
    }

    // this is just a browser json support/compatibility workaround
    if (request.JsonAccepted)
        return Json(status);
    else
        return Json(status, "text/plain");
}
```

The FileStatus class I use as a return value and transform it into json (for the UploadFile jquery module):

```
public class FileStatus
{
    public const string HandlerPath = "/";

    public string group { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string progress { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
    public string delete_url { get; set; }
    public string delete_type { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }

    public FileStatus()
    {
    }

    public FileStatus(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        SetValues(fileInfo.Name, (int)fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FullName);
    }

    public FileStatus(string fileName, int fileLength, string fullPath)
    {
        SetValues(fileName, fileLength, fullPath);
    }

    private void SetValues(string fileName, int fileLength, string fullPath)
    {
        name = fileName;
        type = "image/png";
        size = fileLength;
        progress = "1.0";
        url = HandlerPath + "/file/upload?f=" + fileName;
        delete_url = HandlerPath + "/file/delete?f=" + fileName;
        delete_type = "DELETE";
        thumbnail_url = "/Content/img/generalFile.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for response...which url is call in $("#file-upload").fileupload({url: 'upload-file');

Comment: That should be url of the Controller action method (in my example called Upload)

Comment: Thank you for your help on this much appreciated :)

Comment: In your example, when you upload to upload-folder/some-guid, how do I create a guid folder for each document uploaded?